# Is a microwave's cooking cavity of particular dimensions according to the characteristics of the input microwave feed?

Tags: microwave, resonance, magnetron

i.e. if I were to connect the magnetron inside my microwave to a slightly different steel box (see pic) of a different size and shape (provided the volume inside was roughly similar to the one in my microwave currently), would it still work? [image]

Commercial Microwaves operate on 2.45GHz apparently. Hence wavelength ~= 12.24cm. 1/2 wavelength = 6.12cm. Could this work? [image]

Comment: umm, i don't think a microwave's cooking enclosure is a resonant cavity.  The microwave power/box size relationship is likely based on energy density compromises for cost/area of the parts, and the target audience.  The box (and sometimes an actual fan) are designed to scatter/reflect the energy around to attempt to heat your food evenly.  By changing the box, hotspots may develop in places you do not expect.

Comment: It is resonant, but how exactly is not easy to say offhand -- one would need simulations, and more importantly it depends on whatever's inside.  Mainly the goal I think is to have enough resonant modes that there is always somewhere for the energy to couple, and that those modes are adequately coupled to the load (food) so that the magnetron doesn't burn up from reflected power or detuning. The heating pattern then varies as well, which is why "stirrers" and spinning plates are common.

Comment: Your bigger problem will be making the new box *accessible*. The door design is a subtle one that prevents microwave leakage from its perimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domestic microwave oven's cavity is multimode. That means it fits many wavelengths across its major dimensions, so it's fairly unpredictable which modes will carry most energy. Once the turntable starts moving food around inside, the dominant modes will be constantly changing. The modes are not going to be nice TE<sub>x00</sub> modes, they will use all three indices, which gives them a lot of freedom to adjust to fit into the cavity and crawl round the food.

This means that small, or even large, increases to the cavity dimensions **ought not** to change how it loads the magnetron significantly.

I would expect a significant change if you brought any dimensions down to much less than a wavelength of 2.45 GHz (of the order of 10 cm), but it doesn't sound like you are going to do that.

Comment: I am actually thinking of making it smaller - I've added proposed dimensions above - can you hazard a guess how this would affect functioning?

Comment: @OliverWalters with two dimensions smaller than a wavelength, I would strongly advise against just powering one up. Dropping 30 cm dimensions down to 6 cm is not my idea of 'slightly'. You may be able to figure out ways to check whether you are getting any nasty antinodes in and around your magnetron, but I am not going to encourage you to try. Industrial RF heaters use fairly low frequencies and cavities designed to operate single mode, so the user knows where the heat is being delivered, but they are designed to run like that, not modified from domestic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the dimensions of the oven were engineered to match the magnetron Output impedance for maximum efficiency or transfer of power therefore minimizing standing waves or power reflected that would overheat and damage the power source.
Any change in those calculated, engineered dimensions
Would alter the resonate frequency match.